# Proxying websocket with react-scripts does not work

Tags: reactjs, websocket, proxy, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

I have a react web application and i use react-scripts for developpment. I use the proxy to proxy the requests and websockets to a backend.

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
  },
  "homepage": "/home"
}
```

I have a setupProxy.js :

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(proxy('/api', {
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9140',
    ws: true
  }));

  app.disable('etag');
}
```

The proxy works fine for http request. The react web application perform a request on `http://localhost:3000/api/foo/bar` and the request is proxied on `http://localhost:9140/api/foo/bar`.

My issue is with websockets. The react web application open a websocket on `ws://localhost:3000/api/foo/bar`, the backend receive the websocket request and upgrade it and respond with a 101 http code. But the react web application never receive this response. The react web application receive a 400 http code response. So the websocket is closed.

I'm trying to find why the react application receive a 400 error. I tried many proxy configurations (i tried the proxy configuration in the `package.json` file, i tried some other possible configurations based on the `http-proxy-middleware` github page).

I found some issue with `http-proxy-middleware` and `react-scripts`:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5280
- https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/112

After some investigation, it seems like the issue comes from `sockjs-node` used by Webpack. It looks like `sockjs-node` catch the request and replace my backend response with an error 400 response.

Does anyone know how to make websockets working with a proxy in a react application in developpment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In create-react-app v3.3.0 websocket proxying is [broken](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8094). Try to downgrade to v3.2.0. I'm still on a v3.3.0 beta version as i depend on nullish coalescing, but i wouldn't generally recommend using a beta version.